# How to rotate camera to 90 degree in left, right, top and bottom side in THREE JS

Tags: three.js

I have four buttons **TOP,  BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT BUTTON** where camera must rotate to 90 degree on the 4 directions on button click without setting the camera position physically(like: camera.position.set(1,0,0)) because when I load a model the camera position changes accordingly to the size of the model.So, I have tried to achieve this by moving the camera to degree to the respective axis. But still it's not working.

Can you help me out with figuring out the mistake in my code.

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vghcnkwa/1/

```
var container;

var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

var cube, mesh, material;

// Create new object by parameters

var createSomething = function(klass, args) {

    var F = function(klass, args) {

        return klass.apply(this, args);

    };

    F.prototype = klass.prototype;

    return new F(klass, args);

};

var wireframeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000,
    wireframe: true,
    opacity: 0.15,
    transparent: true
});
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    wireframe: true
});
var smoothMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    flatShading: true,
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
})

// Cube

var materials = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

    materials.push([new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: Math.random() * 0xffffff,
        wireframe: false
    })]);

}



var geometriesParams = [

    {
        type: 'BoxGeometry',
        args: [200, 200, 200, 2, 2, 2, materials]
    },
    {
        type: 'TorusGeometry',
        args: [100, 60, 4, 8, Math.PI * 2]
    },
    {
        type: 'TorusKnotGeometry',
        args: [100, 30],
        scale: 0.25,
        meshScale: 4
    },
    {
        type: 'SphereGeometry',
        args: [100, 3, 3],
        meshScale: 2
    },
    {
        type: 'IcosahedronGeometry',
        args: [100, 1],
        meshScale: 2
    },
    {
        type: 'CylinderGeometry',
        args: [25, 75, 200, 8, 3]
    },
    {
        type: 'OctahedronGeometry',
        args: [200, 0],
        meshScale: 2
    },
    {
        type: 'LatheGeometry',
        args: [
            [
                new THREE.Vector2(0, 0),
                new THREE.Vector2(50, 50),
                new THREE.Vector2(10, 100),
                new THREE.Vector2(50, 150),
                new THREE.Vector2(0, 200)
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        type: 'TextGeometry',
        args: ['&', {
            size: 200,
            height: 50,
            curveSegments: 1
        }]
    },
    {
        type: 'PlaneGeometry',
        args: [200, 200, 4, 4]
    }

];

var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load('fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function(font) {

    geometriesParams[8].args[1].font = font;

});

var info;
var subdivisions = 2;
var geometryIndex = 0;

// start scene

init();
animate();

function nextSubdivision(x) {

    subdivisions = Math.max(0, subdivisions + x);
    addStuff();

}

function nextGeometry() {

    geometryIndex++;

    if (geometryIndex > geometriesParams.length - 1) {

        geometryIndex = 0;

    }

    addStuff();

}

function switchGeometry(i) {

    geometryIndex = i;

    addStuff();
}

function updateInfo() {

    var params = geometriesParams[geometryIndex];

    var dropdown = '<select id="dropdown" onchange="switchGeometry(this.value)">';

    for (var i = 0; i < geometriesParams.length; i++) {
        dropdown += '<option value="' + i + '"';

        dropdown += (geometryIndex == i) ? ' selected' : '';

        dropdown += '>' + geometriesParams[i].type + '</option>';
    }

    dropdown += '</select>';

}

function addStuff() {

    if (cube !== undefined) {

        geometry.dispose();
        smooth.dispose();

        scene.remove(group);
        scene.remove(cube);

    }


    var modifier = new THREE.BufferSubdivisionModifier(subdivisions);


    var params = geometriesParams[geometryIndex];

    geometry = createSomething(THREE[params.type], params.args);

    // Scale Geometry

    if (params.scale) {

        geometry.scale(params.scale, params.scale, params.scale);

    }

    smooth = modifier.modify(geometry);

    updateInfo();

    // var TypedArrayHelper = function (size, registers, register_type, array_type, unit_size, accessors)
    var colors = new TypedArrayHelper(0, 1, THREE.Color, Float32Array, 3, ['r', 'g', 'b']);

    for (var i = 0; i < smooth.attributes.position.array.length / 3; i++) {

        var hue = (smooth.attributes.position.array[(i * 3) + 1] / 200) + 0.5;
        colors.register[0].setHSL(hue, 1, 0.5);
        colors.push_element(colors.register[0]);

    }

    colors.trim_size();
    smooth.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors.buffer, 3));

    group = new THREE.Group();
    scene.add(group);

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    group.add(mesh);

    cube = new THREE.Mesh(smooth, smoothMaterial);
    var wireframe = new THREE.Mesh(smooth, wireframeMaterial);
    cube.add(wireframe);

    cube.scale.setScalar(params.meshScale ? params.meshScale : 1);
    scene.add(cube);

    group.scale.copy(cube.scale);

}

function init() {

    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    info = document.createElement('div');
    info.style.position = 'absolute';
    info.style.top = '10px';
    info.style.width = '100%';
    info.style.textAlign = 'center';
    info.innerHTML = ' ';
    container.appendChild(info);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 500;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf0f0f0);

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
    light.position.set(1000, 1000, 2000);
    scene.add(light);

    addStuff();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // container.appendChild( stats.dom );
    //

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}
$('#btnTop').on('click', function(e) {
    var radius = 10;
    var angle = 90;
    camera.position.x = camera.position.x + radius * Math.cos(angle);
    controls.update();
});
$('#btnBack').on('click', function(e) {
    alert("test alert")
});
$('#btnLeft').on('click', function(e) {});
$('#btnRight').on('click', function(e) {});
$('#btnBottom').on('click', function(e) {});
$('#btnFront').on('click', function(e) {});


function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

//

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: on click `controls.reset(); camera.position.set( X, Y, Z ); controls.update();`

Comment: can you update in fiddle if possible @WestLangley

Comment: This one time I will: https://jsfiddle.net/cxw2qjLz/